# Where can I find a historic recipe for red cherry-onion jam?

Tags: middle-ages, cultural-history, food, europe

A while back, I had duck with red cherry-onion jam at a medieval restaurant. Allegedly, it was a historic recipe, originally prepared in 1445 for the wedding of one of René d’Anjou’s daughters.

As for background information that might help in the search, René d’Anjou had two daughters who survived to adulthood:

Yolande (2 November 1428 – 23 March 1483), married Frederick ΙΙ of Lorraine, count of Vaudemont, at Nancy in 1445;

Margaret (23 March 1430 – 25 August 1482), married King Henry VI of England, at Titchfield Abbey in Hampshire, also in 1445.

In conclusion, the dish could have been served at either daughter’s wedding. From the prominence of the grooms one might infer that Margaret’s wedding would more likely be referred to as the wedding of Henry VI rather than “of one of René d’Anjou’s daughters”, making Yolande’s wedding the slightly more likely candidate. Maybe the place of the weddings (Nancy vs. Titchfield Abbey, Hampshire), along with culinary traditions, can provide some more hints.

Does anyone have an idea where I can find the recipe, or where to start looking?

Comment: to the downvoter: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/112294/looking-for-a-historic-recipe-for-red-cherry-onion-jam?noredirect=1#comment178593_112294 suggested that I ask here. Thanks, once again, for the <irony> very constructive </irony> downvoting without explanation.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE.  I'm not the downvoter in this case, but it generally helps if you tell us where you've already searched.  After all, from the tooltip, lack of evidence for prior research effort is an *explicit* reason for downvoting.

Comment: How about *Le Ménagier de Paris*? Late 14th century guidebook. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_M%C3%A9nagier_de_Paris

Comment: Good starting point, along with Le Viandier and possibly Du fait de cuisine (of which have not yet found the text online). However, I didn’t find anything in Le Viandier or the excerpt from Le Ménagier de Paris I could find online.

Comment: Medieval recipes tend not to have the details you might expect from modern recipes (quantities, times etc.).  So you might not expect much more than softening onions (possibly red) for an extended time, add sugar (or perhaps honey) and vinegar (or perhaps wine or cider) and then pitted cherries and any other flavours, and boil most of the liquid off.

Comment: Here's one with onions and raisins: http://www.medievalcuisine.com/Euriol/recipe-index/gesotten-zwibelsalat german, not french; 16th not 15th century.  Many other ancient recipes on the same site.

Comment: Guessing: One way to make this look more interesting *and* instantly easier to research (?): name who that daughter was, whom she married and where? Given the year it should be fairly obvious?

Comment: @LаngLаngС theoretically a good point, I have edited the question. In practice, though, two daughters (the only ones to survive to adulthood) got married in that year, thus it is not quite as obvious as it may seem at first.